# Prove that $f$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be defined by

$$ f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\biggl\lvert \frac{y}{x^2} \biggr\rvert e^{-\bigl\lvert \frac{y}{x^2} \bigr\rvert} , \quad \text{ if $x \neq 0$} \\
0, \qquad \qquad \quad \text{if $x = 0$.}
\end{cases}
$$

Prove that $f$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

Prove that $f$ is continuous along any line passing through the origin.

Hi so I am really stuck here. I am not sure what method to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You could go like this. If it was continuous, then the limit of the function when $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$ should be the same while approaching the point through any possible trajectory. If we then find two trajectories for which the limit is different, then it will be discontinuous: try parabolas ($y=mx^2$) and lines ($y=mx$).

For proving they're continuous on lines you will have to substitute $y=mx$ and make the same calculation as before.

Particularly, in the case of parabolas all variables vanish, and you have a constant function $|m|e^{-|m|}$, which if obviously different from $f(0,0)=(0,0)$ if $m\not=0$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Show that along the curve $y=x^2, \ \displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)\neq f(0,0).$ What is the limit along the lines $y=kx$?