# Proof explanation $f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{2y^4-x^3}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if }(x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases} $ not differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

> $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{2y^4-x^3}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if }(x,y) \neq (0,0)
>  \\
>  0  & \text{if }(x,y) = (0,0) \end{cases} $$
> Show that the function is not differentiable at the origin.

---

I have a specific question about a step they did in the book so I will skip the part where they showed that it is continuous and when they calculated the partial derivatives at the origin.
we have $f_x(0,0)=-1$ and $f_y(0,0)=0.$

Now we need to show $$\lim \limits_{\Delta x,\Delta y \to 0,0}=\frac{f(\Delta x, \Delta y) - f(0,0)-f_x(0,0) \cdot \Delta x - f_y(0,0) \cdot \Delta y}{\sqrt{\Delta x^2+ \Delta y^2}} \ne0.$$
We substitute what we have and get $\frac{2 \Delta y^4 -\Delta x^3}{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}+\Delta x$ and finally put everything where it belongs:
$$\frac{2 \Delta y^4 +\Delta x \cdot \Delta y^2}{(\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.$$

**Now is the part where I could not understand**: they just  calculated as $\Delta x = \Delta y$ and got $\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt2}$ then they did the limit as $\Delta x \to 0^+$ and their final answer is $$\lim \limits_{\Delta x0^+} \varepsilon(\Delta x, \Delta y) =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt2} \not = 0.$$

Why would they calculate  $\Delta x = \Delta y$? What is the reason behind it? Is it even possible?

Sorry, hopefully my English and translations are correct and understandable.

Comment: One way to approach, if it is differentiable at that point then it must be continuous? So, is it continuous?

Comment: @nozalp10 It is. The OP told it.

Comment: @nozalp10 It is continuous we have to show that in the first part , then in the second part calculate the partial derivatives by definitions

Comment: @Kobrakixx and OkParadox [This looks very much like a FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=f%28x%2Cy%29+not+differentiable+at+%280%2C0%29). Let us vote to close as a (multi)duplicate instead of editing an official answer.

Comment: The following duplicate (among many others) answers your question: [How to prove this function isn't differentiable at origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4156990/how-to-prove-this-function-isnt-differentiable-at-origin). The point is that in order to prove $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}g(x,y)\ne0,$ it suffices to  prove $\lim_{t\to0}g((x(t),y(t))\ne0,$ for some well chosen functions $x(t),y(t)$ which tend to $0$ with $t.$

Comment: Just before closing , when exactly can i do this I still don't understand.. I don't mind the final answer as I have it just this specific part

Comment: You can do what I wrote in my previous comment 48 min ago (i.e. choose some "bad" path) absolutely everywhen you have to prove  by contradiction that a limit of a function of several variables does not exist, or is distinct from some particular value. This is simply due to the composition of limits: if $\lim_{(0,0)}g=L$ and if $\lim_0(x,y)=(0,0)$ then $\lim_0 g\circ(x,y)=L.$

Comment: Note that a "bad path" is not necessarily a [line like here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4156999/386889) or [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4151163/386889). You will sometimes have to look among curves to find a counterexample to disprove the limit.

Comment: Like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318133).

Answer (score 1):

In case of one variable function in order to show differentiability at a fixed point we check left and right derivatives e.g. we approaching to the point by two possible sides. Meanwhile, in case of plane there are infinitely many paths approaching to a fixed point and it should be equal in every possible one. In your example, the path $Y=X$ shows that the limit not tend to zero.

Comment: Which controversy?

Comment: Sorry for my English

Answer (score -1):

When calculating the limit of the difference quotient as ***Δx*** and ***Δy*** approach 0, the authors substituted

**Δx = Δy**
in order to simplify the expression. This is a common technique used when dealing with functions that have certain symmetries or properties.

In this case, since the function  ***f(x,y)***  is symmetric with respect to ***x*** and ***y*** (meaning that if we swap ***x*** and ***y***, the function remains the same), it makes sense to assume that ***Δx = Δy.*** This simplifies the expression by allowing us to replace

***Δx^2 + Δy^2*** with ***2Δx^2***

which is easier to work with.

Technically speaking, it is not necessary to assume that ***Δx = Δy***, but doing so can make the calculations simpler. However, it is important to note that the limit of the difference quotient must still be evaluated as both **Δx** and **Δy** approach **0**, and not just as **Δx** approaches 0. This is because we need to consider all possible ways in which ***Δx*** and ***Δy*** can approach 0 in order to determine whether the function is differentiable at the origin.

Comment: This function is *not* symmetric. $f(1,0) = 2$ while $f(0,1) = -1$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @OP: In your example, you don't "need to consider all possible ways in which Δx and Δy can approach 0". One way was sufficient to disprove differentiability.

Answer (score -1):

For the simplicity, let me write $h=\Delta x$, $k=\Delta y.$

I think the explanation by contradiction is easier to understand (but this is essentially the same as what your textbook says.)

Supposing $f$ is differentiable at origin, then
$$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)h-f_y(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0.$$
This means that for **any** approach of $(h,k)\to(0,0)$,
we have
$$\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)h-f_y(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\to 0.$$
Thus, if $(h,k)$ approaches to $(0,0)$ with $h=k, h>0$, then we must have
$$\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)h-f_y(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\to 0\quad\cdots \bigstar$$

However, if $(h,k)$ approaches to $(0,0)$ with $h=k, h>0$, then (in this situation, $(h,k)\to(0,0)$ is equivalent to $h\to +0$)
\begin{align}
&\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)h-f_y(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{2k^4-h^3}{h^2+k^2}-0+h-0\cdot k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{2h^4-h^3}{2h^2}+h}{\sqrt{2h^2}}\\
&=\frac{h}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\\
&\to\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\quad\mathrm{as}\quad h\to+0.
\end{align}
This contradicts $\bigstar.$ Therefore $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0).$

---

Anyway, $$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)h-f_y(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$$ means that for any approach of $(h,k)\to(0,0)$, we have
$$\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)h-f_y(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\to 0$$ so if we find **specific**  approach of $(h,k)\to(0,0)$ such that $$\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-f_x(0,0)h-f_y(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\color{red}{\nrightarrow} 0,$$ then $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0).$